# How to simultaneously access a global variable used inside while loop in another function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, global-variables

I want to access the value of a variable which is being modified by the while loop, to be continuously printed outside loop. What I did:

```
x=0

def funcA():
    global x
    while True:
        x=x+1
        return x

def funB():
    print x
```

Now, I want x to keep print continously:

```
   1
   2
   3  and so on!
```

But it does not. I DONT WANT THIS:

```
def funB():
   while True:
       print x
```

That is to say that I dont want any while loop inside function funcB().
Thank you very much!

Comment: The `while True` in your `funcA` doesn't do anything at all, because the first time through the loop, you just `return`.

Comment: If you want `funB` to continually print the value of `x`, you're going to either need to loop within `funB` or have `funB` call a function that loops(or pass `funB` to a function that loops and calls `funB`).  `print x` on its own will not repeatedly print a value.  It might be worth clarifying what you're actually trying to do here, as it's hard to understand from your example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you could use a [generator](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/).

```
def funcA():
    x = 0
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 1

def funcB():
    for x in funcA():
        print x #=> 1, 2, 3...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I could solve the problem with your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a useful loop *anywhere*. In `funcA`, you have a `while True:`, but it just does a `return` every time through the loop, meaning it just runs once.

So, you could put a loop *outside* the two functions:

```
while True:
    funcA()
    funB()
```

Or, you could fix `funcA` so it loops forever instead of just once, then call `funB` from inside it:

```
def funcA():
    global x
    while True:
        x=x+1
        funB()
```

Or you could pass `funB` to `funcA` and have it call whatever it gets passed:

```
def funcA(*functions):
    global x
    while True:
        x=x+1
        for function in functions:
            functions()

funcA(funB)
```

Or you could make `funcA` `yield` each time through the loop instead of `return`ing, and use that to drive `funB`:

```
def funcA():
    global x
    while True:
        x=x+1
        yield x

for _ in funcA():
    funB()
```

Or… there are all kinds of things you could do. The question is what you actually *want* to do. If you can explain that, someone can help you write it.

---

Meanwhile, you don't actually need a global variable in most of these cases. Given that `funcA` is already trying to `return x`, you can just pass the returned value in to `funB` in the outer-loop version, or pass `x` itself to `funB` and to `function` in the next two versions, and pass the yielded value in the generator version, …

Answer (score 1):

A callback would work and avoids the need for a global `x`:

```
def funcA(cb):
    x = 0
    while True:
        x=x+1
        cb(x)

def funB(a):
    print a    

funcA(funB)
```